# Twilio Programmable Chat JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have implemented a Twilio chat client (Programmable Chat) in my web application. It works great in FireFox and Chrome. When a message is sent to a channel it calls a web hook (onMessageSent).

I think there may be an issue calling web hooks when a message is sent from a client that's using Internet Explorer.

I can be logged into my application in Chrome and IE, and have both clients chatting on the same channel. When I send a message from the client in Internet Explorer, the message is immediately carried over to the client in Chrome. However, it takes minutes to trigger the web hook. Often times, when it finally does call the web hook, it calls it multiple times. Occasionally, it doesn't call it at all.

Has anyone noticed this before? Any thoughts on why this would work in Chrome and FF and not IE?

Comment: That is strange. I'd get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who will raise this with the correct team and keep you informed. I've also let the team know.

Comment: Thanks, @philnash. I created a ticket Jan. 5th and have yet to hear any type of feedback. I figured I would try here too.

Comment: Which version of IE is this happening in?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64 bit
Service Pack 1
IE 11 & IE 10

Comment: Thanks! Can you email me at philnash@twilio.com with your ticket number and I'll try to get that in front of the right people too. Sorry it's taken a while to get back to you.